# Why am I getting a NameError when I try to reference to a file variable I have previously defined in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write to a .txt file, but I get the error

```
File "C:\Python34\Timer.py", line 262, in Lap
outfile.write(timenow + str(tempo)+ "\n")
NameError: name 'outfile' is not defined
```

I have already defined 'outfile' in:

```
class StopWatch(Frame):  
    """ Implements a stop watch frame widget. """                                                                
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):        
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw, bg="black")
        self._start = 0.0        
        self._elapsedtime = 0.0
        self._running = 0
        self.timestr = StringVar()
        self.lapstr = StringVar()
        self.e = 0
        self.m = 0
        self.makeWidgets()
        self.laps = []
        self.lapmod2 = 0
        self.today = time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H-%M-%S", time.localtime())
        timenow = time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        outfile = open("lap_timings_and_time.txt","wt") 
        outfile.write(timenow+ "\n")
```

And tried to write to the file 'lap_timings_and_time.txt' in the following code:

```
def Lap(self):
    '''Makes a lap, only if started'''
    tempo = self._elapsedtime - self.lapmod2
    timenow = time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    if self._running:
        self.laps.append(self._setLapTime(tempo))
        self.m.insert(END, self.laps[-1])
        self.m.yview_moveto(1)
        self.lapmod2 = self._elapsedtime
        outfile.write(timenow + str(tempo)+ "\n")
```

I'm a beginner at Python and can't figure out why the error is occurring. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
outfile.write(timenow + str(tempo)+ "\n")
```

This should be:

```
self.outfile.write(timenow + str(tempo)+ "\n")
```

You'll also want to change the last two lines of your constructor (`__init__`) to:

```
    self.outfile = open("lap_timings_and_time.txt","wt") 
    self.outfile.write(timenow+ "\n")
```

**Update:** A bit of explanation as per the comments...

What you were encountering was a "Scoping Issue". (See: [Scoping and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)).

In general referencing attributes of an object requires "explicit" referenecing.

i.e:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_attr = "foo"

    def foo(self):
        return self.my_attr
```

You cannot reference `my_attr` by the expression `return my_attr` as `my_attr` is neither in `Foo.foo()` scope nor part of the module's scope or even declared a global.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you also want to make outfile a member of self as self.outfile when you open it as well:
self.outfile = open("lap_timings_and_time.txt","wt")

Comment: +1 for this answer, although you might want to mention why it needs to be like this - i.e. scope of the original outfile variable etc.